# TypeConverter is not called when data binding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, localization, typeconverter

I'm trying to bind an enum to Picker control and display localized names to the user. I use the same code that works perfectly in my WPF app, but for some reason it doesn't work in Xamarin Forms and it displays enum's named constants instead of localized names. It looks like that TypeConverter is not called.
I checked that the type converter works as expected: `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Country)).ConvertTo(Country.sr, typeof(string)) as string;` returns localized name.

Here is my type converter class

```cs
    public class EnumDescriptionTypeConverter : EnumConverter
    {
        public EnumDescriptionTypeConverter(Type type)
            : base(type)
        {
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
                    if (fi != null)
                    {
                        var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
                        return ((attributes.Length > 0) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(attributes[0].Description))) ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
                    }
                }

                return string.Empty;
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

and my DescriptionAttribute class

```
    public class LocalizedDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
    {
        ResourceManager _resourceManager;
        readonly string _resourceKey;

        public LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(string resourceKey, Type resourceType)
        {
            _resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceType);
            _resourceKey = resourceKey;
        }

        public override string Description
        {
            get
            {
                string description = _resourceManager.GetString(_resourceKey);
                return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description) ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", _resourceKey) : description;
            }
        }
    }
```

and my enum

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
    public enum Country
    {
        [LocalizedDescription("sl", typeof(Resource))]
        sl,
        [LocalizedDescription("sr", typeof(Resource))]
        sr,
        [LocalizedDescription("th", typeof(Resource))]
        th
    }
```

Comment: In Forms , using [Value Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface) you can refer to this .

Comment: But why TypeConverter doesn't work? I have a big project and replacing type converters would be a lot of effort.

Comment: I know that the IValueConverter would work, but I would like to avoid source code refactoring, since it will be a lot of effort.

Comment: Generally , `IValueConverter` is used in Xamarin Forms , then suggest you to have a try with it . Later I will have a try with `TypeConverter` , if solution will update here .